# How can I wrap a system library/dependency in a catkin package, and then use that package to provide the system lib in other packages?

Tags: cmake, ros

I have a system library, such as OpenCV 3.0.0 (for example), installed on my computer in the directory `/opt/OpenCV3`.

I want to wrap the dependencies on OpenCV in my own package, `opencv3`. This way I can use catkin like this:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  opencv3
)
```

So I went ahead and created the opencv3 package. I'm able to find the system library's external .cmake file and build. Here are the important parts of `opencv3`'s `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "/opt/OpenCV3")
...
find_package(catkin REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV 3.0.0 EXACT)
...
catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES opencv3
#  CATKIN_DEPENDS
   DEPENDS OpenCV
)
```

Now when I include `opencv3`, my custom package, in other packages as a dependency, the other packages cannot find the OpenCV libraries, and thus they cannot link/build! The OpenCV include directories do transfer over to other packages, however. So when I have this in my `CMakeLists.txt` of other packages which use `opencv3`:

```
message(STATUS ${opencv3_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

I get the output:

```
/opt/OpenCV3/include
```

Which is correct. I just can't find out how the `DEPENDS` field of `catkin_package`(...) makes the system dependency libraries transfer to new packages. `catkin_LIBRARIES` and `opencv3_LIBRARIES` did not have the OpenCV libraries in them either...

Answer (score 0):

I ended up following the instructions here: http://docs.ros.org/hydro/api/catkin/html/howto/system_library_dependencies.html

Even though I was finding OpenCV with `find_package`(), the exported `OpenCV_LIBRARIES` variable did not include full paths to the library files, only the names. This caused the libraries to not show up in other packages which included my `opencv3` package.

The solution was to create a variable which contained the full path to the OpenCV libraries, and place that variable in the `LIBRARIES` part of `catkin_package`(). Only then were packages dependent on `opencv3` able to link and build properly.

I'm mostly happy with this solution, but it still requires me to create a custom variable which contains the absolute paths to all OpenCV libraries. I would much rather just have `DEPENDS OpenCV` in `catkin_package`() and be done with it.